# Google's Way to Represnt List of Links in HTML / CSS

Tags: html, css, semantic-web

I noticed that Google uses HTML table to represent their "Goooooooooogle" pagination links. Is that semantically correct way? What would be the implications if this method is used in a website?

And why would the developers use table in the first place, when inline or floating elements would give the same result?

[image: HTML code of Goooooooooogle]

Comment: Semantic? No, but they're Google, what do they care? Are they worried about SEO rankings on *their* main search page..probably not! >)

Comment: Anyway, this question is really off-topic for SO since it's inviting opinions and is not about solving a specific programming problem.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question was closed as opinion based. The question is pretty straightforward. The answer is an unambiguous no, it's not semantically correct. And the other answer is, none; no implications whatsoever, except that Google is setting a bad example.

Comment: That leaves only the third question, why? Which happens to be opinion based, but I can guess the answer is, to save a byte or two. And this being Google, a byte per page request quickly adds up!